# Java: exception reading a file into a string

Tags: java, readline

```
static void parse(String fileName) throws IOException{
    FileReader fileReader=new FileReader((fileName));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    String string;
    do{
        string=bufferedReader.readLine();
        stringBuilder.append(string);
        }while(!string.equals(null));
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());


}
```

I try to make the read the whole file into a string using StringBuilder. But I get error in while loop. why?

Comment: Ah... the old `equals(null)` question.  Think about what `equals(null)` really means! :-)

Comment: (This issue isn't `(x).equals(null)` - albeit a useless construct - so much as `(null).equals(x)` ..)

Answer (score 2):

Following is how your loop should look like

```
while((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                
    stringBuilder.append(string);
}
```

The problem with your version is that `string.equals(null)` will eventually end up in an NPE. Also, note that `String.equals()` will always return false for `null` argument.

Comment: The other problem with the code as originally written is that `stringBuilder.append(null)` will append the String `"null"`.

Comment: When there is no more line left to read, `bufferedReader.readLine()` returns null and hence you will get a `NullPointerException` at `string.equals(null)`. So the application terminates at that point not the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with

```
string.equals(null)
```

If string is null you can not call equals method on it.